# iMac 2017(27inch) kernel panics, and won't boot

Tags: imac, crash, kernel-panic

I'm currently having a issue with iMac 18,3. It kernel panics and won't boot - Instead, it shows:

```
panic(cpu 8 caller 0xffffff881e76a6ef): initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 6 subcode 8x9 description: dyld shared cache mapping not covered by code signature

uuid info:
 0x18ce88888uuid = <33db4e37-bc29-37a4-92ab-30328e66a8fa>
 0x183aa7700uuid = <15c46340-04e8-3e39-82a6-6354728d4720>

Thread 8 crashed

RAX: 0x0000000002888289, RBX: 0x0000000000000009, RCX: 0x00007fff5c157818, RDX: 0x00007fff5c157498
RSP: 0x00007fff5c157818, RBP: 0x00007fff5c157878, RSI: 0x0000000000000009, RDI: 0x0000000000000006
R8:  0x00007fff5c157898, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000014, R11:0x0000000000000246
R12: 0x0000000000000014, R13: 0x00007fff5c157498, R14: 0x0000000000000006, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000000246, RIP: 0x000000018ceb19ee, CS:  0x0000000000000007, SS: 0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff006d66f780
0x000000010ceb19ee
0x000000010ceb1464
0x000000010ce8c793
0x000000010ce8eb8f
0x000000010ce89249
0x000000010ce89036
0x0000000000000001


Mac OS version:
Not yet set

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Sun Jun 2 20:26:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.50~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 97700CB3-2647-3AE4-A7F2-BA2F41FA8791
System model name: iMac18,3 (Mac-BE000AF8C5EB4FA2)
```

I've wrote this with my hands so there may be a typo.

Any ideas? I've tried:

- Resetting NVRAM, SMC
- Apple Diagnostics (which gives no error)
- Safe boot (which doesn't boot)
- Disk first aid via mac recovery mode's disk utility (which gives no error)

Note: There's no third-party external drive or peripherals, it just has Magic mouse/Magic keyboard.

I'm highly suspecting it's caused by hardware (even though Apple Diagnostics said no issue were found), but I wanted to make sure if it's hardware issue or software issue. Problem is, this iMac isn't actually mine, but my colleague's. I told him numerous times to take a backup, but he didn't listen - So, we need data.

Any help would be appreciated.

***Edit:***

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list internal
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage ⁨Macintosh Hd⁩            27.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage ⁨Macintosh Hd⁩            999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Recovery HD⁩             650.0 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Macintosh⁩               +1.0 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2, disk0s2
                                 96B85A8B-276E-4D44-863D-AE38C6EF52D6
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 05E55E82-9EC2-431D-9A4D-82121C76C853
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh Hd
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1026896293888 B (1.0 TB)
    Free Space:   20480 B (20.5 KB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 3BCD9C9A-F0BD-4DCF-8019-6F471D0853C5
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345127424 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 14901EE2-0537-462C-928B-02968D6AEC66
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     27551166464 B (27.6 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 280233FF-FD5A-4D93-8C5E-F209E37001E9
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 96B85A8B-276E-4D44-863D-AE38C6EF52D6
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1025980628992 B (1.0 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh
            Volume Name:           Macintosh
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil cs info disk3
Core Storage Properties:
   Role:                       Logical Volume (LV)
   UUID:                       96B85A8B-276E-4D44-863D-AE38C6EF52D6
   Parent LVF UUID:            280233FF-FD5A-4D93-8C5E-F209E37001E9
   Parent LVG UUID:            05E55E82-9EC2-431D-9A4D-82121C76C853
   Device Identifier:          disk3
   LV Status:                  Online
   Conversion State:           NoConversion
   LV Conversion Progress:     100%
   Content Hint:               Apple_HFS
   LV Name:                    Macintosh
   Volume Name:                Macintosh
   LV Size:                    1025980628992 B
```

Comment: Have you try boot in Internet Recovery Mode (cmd+alt+r at boot)? If yes, can you from the terminal in Recovery mode (Top menu/Utilities/Terminal), give the results of the command `diskutil list internal`. To add this informations at your question you can open a second terminal (cmd+n) and run the command `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/safari`that open Safari to acces the forum.

Comment: @Jean_JD I added information in my post.

Comment: Perfect. Can you add now the result of `diskutil cs list` and do you know what is the actual System Version?

Comment: @Jean_JD I've added info, and I think it was High Sierra 10.13.5 or 6.

Comment: What do you want do? Save data to an external disk (formated HFS+ with a Partition scheme GUID) and try boot on this external disk or reinstall the system? 
Normally the second operation is risk-free if you have a backup. But personally I recommend doing a backup first.

Comment: Can you add the result of command `diskutil cs info disk3`?

Comment: @Jean_JD Well, luckily we have spare newest Mac mini in our storage room. I asked him if he wanted to use it, he said yes, so if it's possible I'd like to extract some important files.  Added info btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130074/discussion-between-jean-jd-and-skye-at).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, during the conversation with Jean_JD, I've replaced iMac 18,3 with Mac mini 9,1.

Cloned the iMac 18,3's HDD to external drive with terminal command (Luckily, I could boot into Recovery mode) `cp -rv %source directory% %target directry%` (`-v`(verbose) isn't normally needed I think), and extracted important files to Mac mini... and it's done.

So, now's the iMac: Luckily, the issue wasn't on hardware. Since I've already extracted data, I've just clean installed MacOS to see if I can use it - yes, it worked. Now I've updated to latest version(`Big Sur 11.6`), and it's working fine.

Not sure what's caused the issue though, maybe the systems got corrupted somehow.
Anyway, big thanks to @Jean_JD .

Comment: Happy for you ;-)

Answer (score -2):

May be removed and cleaned the RAM

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).